# Chrome XMLHttpRequest readyState===4 returns empty responseText

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-chrome, xmlhttprequest

I'm having a problem where `httpReq.responseText` is empty after `readyState` is `4` in Chrome (Version 33.0.1750.149 m). When I debug through and stop on the `console.log(url)` line, `readyState` is an empty string, and looking in the Network tab, chrome shows an empty response in the "Response" section for the url. Nothing surprising there.

What's surprising is that as soon as I let the javascript continue from that breakpoint, the Network tab populates the response section. I know for certain my server is returning data, and the url is from the same domain (localhost). When I tested in firefox, it works fine.

My code looks like this:

```
    var httpReq = new XMLHttpRequest();

    httpReq.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if( httpReq.readyState === 4 ) {
            if( httpReq.status === 200 ) {
                console.log(url)
                result.return(httpReq.responseText)
            } else {
                if(!result.isResolved)
                    result.throw(new Error('Error in request'))
            }
        }
    }

    httpReq.open('GET', url, true);
    httpReq.send(null);
```

Any ideas what might be going on?

**Update**: if I change the `.open` call to `httpReq.open('GET', url, false);` it works. Something must be going wrong with the `onreadystatechange` function - is this a bug in chrome?

**Update**: I made a minimal repro of this. I have two separate ajax functions in my code (one from a module I don't control). One of them seems to be doing a synchronous http request. Here's a repro:

```
var url = '/'
var httpReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
var httpReq2 = new XMLHttpRequest();

httpReq.onreadystatechange = function() {
    console.log('a '+httpReq.readyState+":"+httpReq.status+' - '+httpReq.responseText.substring(0,40))
};
httpReq2.onreadystatechange = function() {
    console.log('b '+httpReq.readyState+":"+httpReq.status+' - '+httpReq.responseText.substring(0,40))
};

httpReq.open('GET', url ); // asynchronous *first*
httpReq.send();
httpReq2.open('GET', url, false); // synchronous *second*
httpReq2.send();
```

Its pretty clear to me now that this is a bug in chrome. I'll file a ticket with them.

Comment: and what does the `result.return()` function do ?

Comment: `result` is a future object https://github.com/fresheneesz/asyncFuture

Comment: Did you try moving the open and send calls above the onreadystatechange handler ?

Comment: Just tried it, it didn't help..

Comment: If setting it to false works, you most likely have a logic/timing issue revolving around where you access the responseText. in other words, you're accessing `responseText` before the `onreadystatechanged` event happens.

Comment: Nope, found a bug in chrome : )

Comment: Is this resolved?. I am getting the same error in chrome.

Comment: is this resolved?

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in Chrome. See the ticket for details:

https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=368444&thanks=368444&ts=1398808430

Comment: @swyx As you can see in that link, they fixed this years ago at this point. Are you still seeing the problem?

Comment: yes I am but i am also a newbie learning AJAX. At this point i am not very sure if the error is chrome related or not. Will report back if it is, if not future readers can assume it was not a chrome bug